# How to create a new function from a method, with fewer arguments?

Tags: c++

I have two classes, ClassA and ClassB.
ClassA has three methods:

```
double Foo(double, ClassB);
double Bar(double (*f)(double));
double Baz(double, ClassB);
```

I would like to define a function Qux inside Foo, based on Baz but without the argument of type ClassB: i.e. of the kind "double Qux(double)" so that I can pass it to Bar:

```
double ClassA::Foo(double x, ClassB y)
{
    // double Qux(double .) = Baz(., y)
    Bar((*Qux))
}
```

Does some one have any idea?

I guess some will answer this is not the good way to do it. So just to explain the concrete situation, I am pricing financial assets using a numerical method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) in order to compute integrals:

```
ClassA: FinancialAsset

ClassB: PrincingModel

Foo: FinancialAsset.Price(date, PrincingModel)

Bar: FinancialAsset.SimpsonMethod(FunctionOneArgument)

Baz: FinancialAsset.FunctionTwoArguments(date, PrincingModel)
```

And I am looking for:

```
Qux: FunctionOneArgument(date) = FinancialAsset.FunctionTwoArguments(date, PrincingModel)
```

I am not sure what is the good way to address this structure. I you have a better / more c++'s way to do it, I'll take :)

Thanks

Comment: I guess you want to use lambda functions and partial applications. Depending on the version of C++ you are using, we might have different solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that exactly, because your Bar function is taking a pointer to a regular function, but you can use this instead:

```
class A {
    ...
  public:
    double Foo(double, ClassB);
    double Bar(std::function<double(double)> f);
    double Baz(double, ClassB);
};


double ClassA::Foo(double x, ClassB y)
{
    auto Qux = [&](double x) { Baz(x,y); };
    return Bar(Qux);
}
```

`std::function` is a more general way of representing function-like objects.  You can convert a regular function, a lambda, or a function object to it.

Comment: This won't compile since the capture `[]` is empty. Write `[&]` instead.

Comment: I can see a lambda there, but what is the `"double Qux(double .) = Baz(., y)"` thing there called?

Comment: @Losiowaty: That was left over from the original code.  I've removed it now.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought it was something necessary though it seemed extremely non-C++'ish.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to comment it `//`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you have C++11 or not, you either want `std::bind` and `std::function` or `boost::bind` and `boost::function` for older C++ versions.

binding allows you to take a function and bind 0 or more of the parameters, or rearrange the parameters. Indeed something you have above would look like this:

```
double ClassA::Foo(double x, ClassB y)
{
    boost::function<double> baz = boost::bind(this, ClassA::Baz, _1, y);
    Bar(baz);
}
```

And Bar's signature would take a `boost::function` instead of a function pointer.

Note my syntax might be slightly off for binding memeber functions, have a look at the documentation for details.

see here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html

Or here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without changing any function signatures (and C++11 or boost), but I wouldn't suggest it if you can avoid it. It's ugly, not thread-safe, and in general not very nice:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
    // some data in B
    int i;
};

struct A
{
    //some data in A
    double d;

    // the functions you defined in A    
    double Foo(double x, B y);
    double Bar(double (*f)(double));
    double Baz(double x, B y);
};

// a poor substitutes for closures
struct
{
    A *a;
    B *b;
} hack;

double Qux(double x2)
{
    // use the stored pointer to call Baz on x2
    return hack.a->Baz(x2, *hack.b);
}

double A::Foo(double x, B y)
{
    // store pointers for use in Qux
    hack.a = this;
    hack.b = &y;

    // do something with x
    d += x;

    double result = Bar(&Qux);

    return result;
}

double A::Bar(double (*f)(double))
{
    // do something with d, call the passed function
    d += 1;
    return f(d);
}

double A::Baz(double x, B y)
{
    // do something with the passed data
    return x + y.i;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.d = 1.25;

    B b;
    b.i = 2;

    std::cout << a.Foo(.25, b) << std::endl; // should be 4.5    

    return 0;
}
```